# Hide the edit link when id is null

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

After foreach when p_id is null then show edit link for that particular row otherwise hide edit link

this is code i have tried with isset function but it hide edit for all row not the particular row

```
<?php foreach($listing as $value): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>  <?php echo $value['name'] ?> </td>
            <?php if(!isset($value["p_id"]) && empty($value["p_id"])) { ?>
            <td> <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/edit/<?php echo $value['id']?>">Edit</a></td>
            <?php } ?>
            <td><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/delete/<?php echo $value['id']?>">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Change the condition `<?php if(isset($value["p_id"])) { ?>`

Comment: I think you forget to add `!` in empty function `!isset($value["p_id"]) && !empty($value["p_id"])`

Comment: @SreelalPMohan yeah i tried this it works thanks, but you have any idea how to hide this from url also

Comment: @itsoftware Which url?

Comment: @SreelalPMohan when user type id in url for example localhost://edit/13 where id 13 's link is hidden

Comment: If you don't want to show the ID, try this. `<a href="#" onclick="location.replace('<?php echo base_url(); ?>/edit/<?php echo $value['id'] ?>')">Edit</a>`

Comment: @SreelalPMohan solved the problem with global helper function for url check

Answer (score 0):

in above statment use OR instead of &&. because this condition wont come true ever.

Answer (score 0):

Use only this:

```
 if($value["p_id"] != '')
 {
  echo //;
 }
```